# Alternative to case_when() for assigning a function to a variable in R

Tags: r, case-when

A (I hope) very simple question.  I would like to use case_when() or something equivalent to it as a clean solution to assign a function to use based on the value of a variable.  So, I want to do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(nycflights13)
#small data frame of new years day flights from JFK
df1<-flights %>% filter(year==2013,month==1,day==1,origin=="JFK")  

#use min_ind as an indicator (in practice this would be a variable from my dataset
min_ind<-1
```

Now, I want an easy way to assign a function to func_test conditional on the value of min_ind. I can do it as:

```
  if(min_ind==1)
    func_test<-min
  if(min_ind!=1)
    func_test<-max
#test it
func_test(df1$distance)
#reverse
min_ind<-0
  if(min_ind==1)
     func_test<-min
  if(min_ind!=1)
     func_test<-max
func_test(df1$distance)
```

This works fine.  When min_ind is 1, I get the min, and when it's not 1, I get the max.  What I'd like to be able to do is do this assignment via case_when() since I have a set of 4 or 5 functions I may want to use conditional on values in the data.  Is something like this possible?

```
func_test<-case_when(
  min_ind==1 ~ min,
  min_ind!=1 ~ max
)
```

I receive an error code of Error in value[[1]][rep(NA_integer_, m)] : 
  object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for `base::switch()`

Answer (score 4):

`case_when` was really designed to be a vectorized function. So both sides of the formula terms should be things that are vector-like and of the same length or recyclable. Functions do not behave like collections. The problem is that things get messy if `min_ind` were anything other than a length 1 vector. Basically it's trying to check that the lengths are compatible. See the error message you get here

```
min_ind <- 1
func_test<-case_when(
  min_ind==1 ~ 1:3,
  min_ind!=1 ~ 4:6
)
# Error: RHS of case 1 (1:3) must be length 1 (the first output), not 3
```

So the error message you get originally is basically because it's trying to extend the length of your function to the same length as the input, which again, doesn't make sense for functions. You can stuff the functions into lists and then extract the first element if you are sure `length(min_ind==1)`

```
min_ind <- 1
func_test<-case_when(
  min_ind==1 ~ list(min),
  min_ind!=1 ~ list(max)
)[[1]]
```

Comment: Nice! I got the exact same solution at the same time you posted yours. :)

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you'll look inside `case_when` you'll see it's trying to treat the RHS values as a list, which R doesn't like when you use base functions. Here's a way to get around it:

```
func_test<-case_when(
     min_ind==1 ~ list(min),
     min_ind!=1 ~ list(max)
 )[[1]]
```

This solution puts the functions into their own lists, then extracts it before they are assigned to func_test.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your error was that `min` doesn't refer to anything in the above code.
It should be:

```
func_test<-case_when(
   min_ind==1 ~ min(df1$distance),
   TRUE ~ max(df1$distance)
)
```

`TRUE` is used when there is only one other option: the index could be either 1 or not 1.

This works ;)

Comment: Thanks. This will work for the values, but what I want is the function to be attached to the variable so I can call the function at a later point using func_test.